# convert html into word using phpword

Tags: php, xml, openxml, phpword

I need to convert html taged paragraph into word document.

For example  i have a text like this

`<ul><li>One</li><li>Two</li><li>Three</li></ul>`  convert this into

- one
- Two
- Three

in word using `phpword` or else get the `xml` format for word document in `php`

Comment: just echo you string.....

Comment: no.. not that i am writhing that content in word document using phpword

Answer (score 3):

If you need display static lists see here:
https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/docs/elements.rst#lists

If you want convert html string to Word list then you need use regex and preg_match

```
<?php
// New Word Document
$phpWord = new PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();

// New portrait section
$section = $phpWord->addSection();

//Extract and add all options
$html = '<ul><li>One</li><li>Two</li><li>Three</li></ul>';
preg_match_all('/<li>(.+?)<\/li>/i', $html, $matches);
foreach ($matches[1] as $option) {
    $section->addListItem('$option', 0);
}

// Save File
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('ListItem.docx');
```

Comment: how can we use this in template `setvalue` property? 

`$template->setValue(list,$list);` like this